# how to test a function in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine

can anyone help me please? I'm trying to test a function that call a firebase functions, but when I call the main function and start to run a firebase functions, I got a error

```
err TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailPasswordLoginAsPromise' of null
```

i don't know what is happen, follow my code:

```html
fdescribe('UserLoginContentComponent', () => {
  let component: UserLoginContentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserLoginContentComponent>;
  let loginComponent = new UserLoginContentComponent(null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
  
  beforeAll(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          SharedModule,
          AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
          RouterTestingModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule
        ],
        declarations: [UserLoginContentComponent],
        providers: [ 
          AuthService,
          AngularFireAuth,
          AngularFirestore,
          LogService,
          LogPublishersService,
          HttpClient,
          HttpHandler
        ]
      }).compileComponents();

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserLoginContentComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      spyOn(loginComponent, 'onSubmit').and.callThrough();
      loginComponent.loginModel.email = 'correct email';
      loginComponent.loginModel.password = 'correct password';
    })
  );

  it('component should be create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Correct login',function(){
    loginComponent.onSubmit().then((x) => {
      console.log('ok:',x)
      //expect something ..
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('err',err)
    })
  });
    
});
```

my Function that I'm calling:

```html
onSubmit() {
    //i'm setting my loginModel in the test with email and password
    console.log('this.loginModel',this.loginModel)

    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
      this.authService.emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(this.loginModel).then(userCredential => {
      // do something..
        this.authService.createOrUpdateUserDataFirestore(userCredential, null, avaliacaoChecklist, null, null).then(s => 
        //updating my user or create one
        }).catch(e => {
          //catch if this doesn't update or create
          });
        });
        res('login OK')
      }).catch(e => {
        //open a diaglog if happen something wrong...
        rej('login Fail')
      });
    })
  }
```

in my authService, my emailloginasPromise is like that :

```html
  emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(login) {

    return new Promise((resolveEPL, rejectEPL) => {

      this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(login.email, login.password)
        .then(credential => {
          this.updateUserWithAuth(credential.user);
          resolveEPL(credential.user);
        }).catch(e => {
          console.error('emailPasswordLogin', e);
          rejectEPL(e);
        });
    });
  }
```

it's my first time with testing jasmine, I studied, but i don't know how I can solve this problem, how call a async func and getting the return.

Comment: Did you check if authService is provided inside constructor ?

Comment: @jakubm now i'm using the  component = fixture.componentInstance;, and is working, that was the problem, no provider for authservice, but isn't working my async function, i call with it('', async((done) => {
   // do my promise ... but my test is executed first, and then my promise, how can i fix it?
}))

Comment: Could you update your question and the code snippets it will be easier for me to see what's going on.

Comment: @jakubm I solved my problem, I posted my answer, thank u for all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i founded the problem, follow the fix:

The authService isn't provide when i'm creating a stance of my class, so now i'm using the component:

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

with this component now I'm calling my method and all providers is working.

Follow my describe:

```html
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { UserLoginContentComponent } from './user-login-content.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { LogService } from 'src/app/shared/logger/log.service';
import { LogPublishersService } from 'src/app/shared/logger/log-publishers.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

fdescribe('UserLoginContentComponent', () => {
  let component: UserLoginContentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserLoginContentComponent>;
  
  beforeAll(function(){
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          SharedModule,
          AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
          RouterTestingModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule
        ],
        declarations: [UserLoginContentComponent],
        providers: [ 
          AuthService,
          AngularFireAuth,
          AngularFirestore,
          LogService,
          LogPublishersService,
          HttpClient,
          HttpHandler
        ]
      }).compileComponents();

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserLoginContentComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();

    });
    
});
```

and how to test this component?

I'm using the follow tests:

```html
it('COrrect login',(async(done) => {
    component.loginModel.email = 'correctemail@gmail.com';
    component.loginModel.password = 'correctpassword';

    await component.onSubmitTest().then((x) => {
      expect(x).toBe('login OK');
    });
    done();
  }));
  
  it('Wrong login (email)',(async(done) => {
    component.loginModel.email = 'wrongemail@gmail.com';
    component.loginModel.password = 'correctpassword';

    await component.onSubmitTest().then(() => {})
    .catch((err) => {
      expect(err).toBe('login Fail');
    })
    done();
  }));
```

My class follow:

```html
onSubmitTest() {
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
      this.authService.emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(this.loginModel).then(() => {
        res('login OK')
      }).catch(e => {
        rej('login Fail')
      });
    })
  }
```

and my authService:

```html
emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(login) {

    return new Promise((resolveEPL, rejectEPL) => {

      this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(login.email, login.password)
        .then(credential => {
          resolveEPL(credential.user);
        }).catch(e => {
          rejectEPL(e);
        });
    });
  }
```

And now all my testing is working with asynchronous method with firebase methods